# Preview multiple videos in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, mediaelement

What is the best way for preview multiple videos in WPF? I want to have more than 10 videos play at once. Something like preview images in file explorer but with playing videos. I tried it with `MediaElement` but when I have more then 4 videos running then videos are lagging (hope it is the right word, it isn´t playing smoothly). So how can I fix this? Is there a way for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the problem of the component that you are using but the problem of CPU / GPU performance. To play 10 videos at a time you will need high end system.

Also it will depend upon your video quality. If they are of high resolution then even in high end systems they will not play smoothly.

Comment: I think that would be this problem but what about some preloading?

Comment: I think at that time also there will be lots of frame will render on live screen so it will take a lot of your GPU and so performance will not be smooth.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying something but you´ve been right. For my needs I must convert my videos to lower quality and then I can play much more videos.